# swift - How to make sure in which protocol or type a specific property is originally defined?

Tags: swift

I always have difficulties in finding the original protocol or type in which a property is defined. For example, I'm not sure where the `randomElement()` method is defined, is it defined in `Collection` or in `RandomAccessCollection` or somewhere else?

How do we make sure where that specific property is originally defined?
I find that Apple's official documentation isn't of much help.
Is there a better website or app that can get the job done nicely?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use Xcode, Command+Control+click on an identifier to go to its declaration.

Also useful:

- Option+click an identifier to see its documentation.
- Command+click to see more available options:

[image: Command+click]

Comment: If you look at the doc, you can find about 75 occurrences of `randomElement()` methods, but I think that method is first declared in `Collection` protocol, don't you think so? I don't think Xcode will help you find out which one is the very first that declared that method.